# Getting wrong betas when doing OLS regression in R

Tags: r, regression

My first question here. This problem have stolen days from my life. I know, it's not that important, but at the same time: I need to know! I know there are many good formulas for making regression. But when I try to do it using good-old arithmetic just to get the hangs of it, I get ridiculous answers on beta.

Beta vector is supposed to be (X'X)^(-1)X'y (where X is the matrix of regressors and y the vector of answers). I'll give one example (and that it's not suitable for OLS is irrelevant - I just want b:s here):

```
X <- matrix(1:10)
y <- matrix(2:11)
b <- (t(X) %*% X)^(-1) %*% t(X) %*% y
```

Which gives b = 1.142857, while summary(lm(y~X)) gives beta = 1 and an intercept of 1. I add a constant to X to get an intercept: X <-cbind(X,1) and the results I get is b = (2.324675,14.5) which doesn't make sense at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The right syntax is `b <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y` because `solve` gives the inverse of the matrix `t(X)%*%X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here. The first is a problem of notation. The power of -1 in the formula actually indicates a matrix inverse. That is calculated with `solve` in R and not with `^-1`, which indicates element-wise reciprocals.

Then, you need to create a design matrix that actually contains an intercept.

```
X <- matrix(1:10)
y <- matrix(2:11)^2
coef(lm(y~X))
#(Intercept)           X 
#        -21          13 

X <- cbind(1, X)
solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y
#     [,1]
#[1,]  -21
#[2,]   13
```

Obviously, you should not actually do this matrix inversion in real world applications (and R's `lm` doesn't do it).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with using `^(-1)` for the inverse. It doesn't work like that for Matrices. `solve` is used to get the inverse of a matrix: https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/matrix.html

```
# use solve 
b <- solve(t(X) %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% y

# fit model without intercept
m <- lm(y~-1+X)
summary(m)

# same coefficients
b
m$coefficients


# with intercept
X2 <- cbind(rep(1, 10), X)

b2 <- solve(t(X2) %*% X2) %*% t(X2) %*% y
m2 <- lm(y~+X)
summary(m2)

b2
m2$coefficients
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 X <- cbind(1, matrix(1:10))
 b<-solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%y
```

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Matrix/versions/0.3-26/topics/solve.Matrix